# Div will not stay in place and moves up when re-sizing browser window

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web design and  have a webpage that I'm creating with a stripe at the bottom of the page that moves up when the browser window is minimized. I would like not see it at all when minimized. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Instead of posting all the html code I have posted the link here: http://52.8.135.18/~lrodrig6/about.html . Here is the CSS for the stripe:

```
div.stripe {
width:100%;
height:9.375em;
position: absolute;
//top:0;
left:0;
bottom: 5.9375em;
background-image: url("space.jpg");
border-top-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-top-color: whitesmoke;
border-bottom-color: whitesmoke;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: you want to hide the div for small windows?

Comment: what I would really like is for the stripe to be part of the background and stay at the bottom so it doesn't block the lion image when screen is resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to get rid of the line when the screen is small?

```
@media (max-width: 320px) { 
    div.stripe { display: none; }
}
```

The above code will make the `div.stripe` invisible if the screen is 320 or smaller. Change the 320 to whatever size you want.

Comment: or you can use max-height in media query if you want to make decision based on window height.

Comment: if i put the @media code in a css file, how would I call it so the div uses it ?

Comment: What do you mean? It's in there, `div.stripe`. Whatever code you put in the @media query will be executed only when the viewport is 320 or smaller. Change the number if you want it to be hidden in larger viewports.

Comment: the @media query goes in the head right ? Where the CSS link is at ?

Comment: No, it goes in your CSS file. Just paste it at the end.

Comment: Cool, thanks got it to work. I thought you had to link it in the head like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 700px)" href="site.css" />`

Comment: You're welcome. It think that if you did it the way you suggest, the stylesheet would only be loaded for devices that are smaller than 700px...

Comment: @cooperstia, yes, your right because when I attempted to do it that way my webpage was missing all the style attributes. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You should  check out Ethan Marcotte's book Responsive Web Design. It explains how to make responsive sites. It includes how to use media queries.